# How to detect whether the map is loaded completely when using the bing map control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, bing-maps

I put a bing map control in my app and loaded map when the app started running, for better experience, I also put a processindicator in the systemtray to tell the user the map is in loding, but I didn' know when the map is loaded completely, so I searched for the documents, but I couldn't find any events like the "Navigating" or "Navigated" method in Webbrowser control. Dose anyone could give me a hand? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MapResolved should do the trick I think. Good luck!